# IDE for php which supports svn,save options auto align etc and open source

Tags: php, ide

i need an IDE which supports php i am from java and i use eclipse for more-than 2 years and it has an php plugin too.but that dont have an many good features as the java has  so i am looking for an IDE dedicated for Php .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My choice is [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) - crossplatform, open source, SVN (and other CVS), supports many tepmlate engines (Smarty, Twig) and one of the fastest full featured IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

[PhpEd](http://www.nusphere.com/) is specific to php and has the best auto-complete and project management features I've encountered in php IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com) because I get to stay in Eclipse where my Java projects are and it has great PHP and Javascript syntax support.